# Back button not displaying using navigation view and toolbar

Tags: android, navigation, androiddesignsupport

I have an application with the following hierarchy:

```
MainActivity (Shows list of dates) 
    | 
ViewPagerFragment (Shows list of children for those dates)
    | 
ChildFragment (Detail View)
```

I am trying to implement the navigation view from the design support library, but am having trouble getting the actual navigation on the toolbar to work.

Here is the Main Activity toolbar:

[image: main activity navigation]

Here is the ViewPagerFragment after navigating there from the main activity, note that there is no back button...

[image: child activity navigation]

Here is the desired toolbar:
[image: desired toolbar]

I am adding fragments using the following code:

```
    getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment, fragment.getClass().getName())
            .addToBackStack(fragment.getClass().getName())
            .commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

Here is the code related to activity startup:

```
protected void setupActionBar() {
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    if (actionBar != null) {
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

And my navigation drawer setup:

```
protected void setupNavigationDrawer() {
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
    actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
}
```

Hitting the hardware back button on the device navigates back properly. I just can't seem to get the back arrow to show up on the drawer toggle... Any suggestions?

Comment: It'd be poor design to have two buttons so close together. DrawerLayout belongs in your root Activity, then any activity you open wouldn't have access to the drawer, but instead have the back button to return to the root.

Comment: I think that you're misunderstanding what I'm asking. The toolbar does have support built-in to act as an action bar and display either the hamburger (for nav drawer opening) or back button icon. Everything was working that way prior to me switching to use the android design support library's navigation view, but now that I've switched the toolbar will not show the back button as it once used to.

Comment: Yes it can display EITHER the drawer menu or back button. I dont think you can have both. If you have a navigation drawer then you cant have the back button. Otherwise how is the toolbar supposed to know what action to take unless you explicitly control the icon and action in your activities. What are you looking for here? drawer or back button or a way to control both?

Comment: I updated the question, I never wanted both buttons to appear at the same time - I'm not sure how that was gleaned from the question. See newly attached picture for desired state when there are fragments in the backstack.

Comment: @jyanks I am facing exactly the same issue and can't find the solution. Could you please help me out by hinting the some code here ?

Comment: You should look at @tanis-7x answer below. That is what fixed it for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To disable the navigation drawer icon and show a different icon instead, you need to call [`setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle.html#setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(boolean)) on your `ActionBarDrawerToggle`.

You may also need to call [`setHomeAsUpIndicator()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle.html#setHomeAsUpIndicator(int)) to specify the icon you want to use instead of the "hamburger" icon.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to reach the ActionBar of the Activity ?

in onViewCreated:

```
Toolbar mToolbar = (Toolbar) view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
((Activity) getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Hi @guillaume_fr, that code is in the main activity call on creation.